# Color based on groups in wordcloud R

Tags: r, word-cloud

I am successfully generating a wordcloud, but I don't know why I cannot color them based on the group. Here is the code:

## word cloud

```
    set.seed(1234)
    wordcloud(words = data$Name, freq = data$freq, min.freq = 1,
              max.words=100, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35,
              scale = c(4,0.8), random.color = FALSE,
              colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2")[factor(data$group)])

    set.seed(1)
    d1 <- data.frame(word=c(stringi::stri_rand_strings(20, 5)), freq=c(sample.int(20,10,100)))
    d1$group <- "group1"
    d1$word <- paste("g1" ,d1$word, sep = "")

    d2 <- data.frame(word=c(stringi::stri_rand_strings(20, 5)),freq=c(sample.int(20,10,100)))
    d2$group <- "group2"
    d2$word <- paste("g2" ,d2$word, sep = "")

    d <- rbind(d1,d2)

    # word cloud
    set.seed(1234)
    wordcloud(words = d$word, freq = d$freq, min.freq = 1,
              max.words=100, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35,
              scale = c(3,0.5), random.color = FALSE,
              colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2")[factor(d$group)])
```

also, when the word cloud in plotted I cannot find all of the instances especially when I zoom, how can I make sure that I can have them very dense so that the plot looks like a cloud?

[image]

Comment: I believe you need the `ordered.colors=TRUE` option in the wordcloud function.

Comment: @Dave2e worked like a charm, thanks! is there any parameter to control the density?

Comment: I think that is governed by the size of the plot window.  I use Rstudio the word clouds are scaled to fill the available space.  If I resize the plot window after plots the spacing becomes irregular.